# How to change firefox developer edition inspector background colour

Tags: firefox-developer-edition

Just started using Firefox Developer Edition and the background colour in Inspector was a lovely black background. Now it's changed to a white colour. Any idea how I can change it back?

I'm on an Apple Mac OS Sierra 10.12.6 and using Firefox Dev Ed 58.0b1

Thanks,

Djuro

Answer (score 0):

doh! there it is in the settings wheel for the inspector element.

[inspector setting screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R567B.png)